# Horrible performance for a ^[a-z]{0,20000}$ regex compilation with regcomp

Tags: regex, performance, memory, libc

I'm wondering why the compilation of such a regex takes up to 70% of my RAM, leading to intense swapping and a load average of 16:

```
strcpy(regexStr,"^[a-z]{0,20000}$" );
regcomp( &regex , regexStr , REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED );
```

The execution time is in the order of minutes (had to kill the process before).
The execution for a `^[a-z]{0,2000}$` (2,000, not 20,000) is around 100ms which is way to much to me.

I use this to check a pattern and at the same time check the length. Ï found regex to be convenient for both. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: @marco: as far as language goes, I can only guess C or C++ (`strcpy`, `regcomp`)

Comment: @Matt That's clear, but there are many C++ regex engines.

Comment: @marcog: yep, sorry it was Libc regex provided functions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest using `strlen` to measure the string length and afterwards the regex `/[^a-z]/` for testing for the absence of non alpha characters. KISS.

BTW, no I don't see any good reason* for why you're getting that kind of performance.

*good reasons obviously don't include bugs or poor design...

edit: turns out, it may be actually a case of [poor design](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

edit2: since the check you're doing is pretty simple you could actually implement in plain C:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<20000 && str[i]!=0; i++)
  if (str[i] < 'a' || str[i] > 'z')
    return -1;
return i;
```

if it returns -1, the string contains a character outside the range a-z; if it returns 20000 the string is longer than 20000 characters; otherwise it returns the string length. (note: this will obiously only work on non-wide char strings)

Comment: With a 491 rep, you should be able to edit your actual answer instead of commenting under it. If not, here's a thumb to get you closer to whatever rep you do need.

Comment: I wish I could do both at the same time (I've setup some kind of input parameters parser/checker based on a bunch of defines and structures. I'll add a "length" field into the parsing structures so that I can handle strlen() separately. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Odds are that under the hood your regex engine is converting your pattern to something like `^(|[a-z]|[a-z][a-z]|[a-z][a-z][a-z]|..)$` which is quadratic in the cardinality of your range.

Comment: It clearly is. Seems a design "flaw". Will cope with it ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the cardinality range is what's killing you. Try using a greedy non-specific cardinality match, such as `"^[a-z]*$"`, coupled with a max length check. It should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider what you are asking the compiler to do. In a naive way, you can consider the regex compilation to be the building of a finite state machine that will only accept strings matching the regex. Consider the state size of a machine that has to keep track of how many characters are in the string, and you should see the problem with your current regex.

Comment: This is very clear in the CAFxX's link. Not read everything, but looks promising. Will have a deeper look at it asap !